# get high quality facebook profile picture with cordova plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm developing ionic 2 app. I'm trying to get high quality image and then resize it to avatar photo.

My code:

```
 _FBUserProfile() {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Facebook.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture.width(600).height(600).as(picture_small),picture.width(360).height(360).as(picture_large)', [])
    .then((profileData) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(profileData));
      return resolve(profileData);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      return reject(err);
    });
});
```

}

But, the photo isn't good quality, since I guess I did something wrong with the resize in this line:

```
picture.width(600).height(600).as(picture_small),picture.width(360).height(360).as(picture_large)', [])
```

How can I get good quality of the photo?

Comment: quality: 100, 
 did u try using this?

Comment: what do you mean? where to write it instead of what?

Comment: pardon !! my bad !! this "quality " works while uploading images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get the public profile picture of the user and you know the user id from the api call then use this url for picture

```
profileData.picture="https://graph.facebook.com/"+profileData.id+"/picture?width=1024&height=1024";
```

Answer (score 6):

You've got a couple of solutions, like using `type large`

```
id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)
```

As explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/